# Virtualenv on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, path, virtualenv

I create a virtualenv with `--system-site-packages`.

But for some strange reasons some paths from `/usr` are before some path in my virtualenv.

That is bad, since I want to be able to overwrite packages in my virtualenv.

In my case requests `requests 2.2.1` is installed via dpkg in `/usr` and my virtualenv needs a newer version. I can install a newer version, but this does not get imported with `import requests`.

```
/home/my-virtualenv/src/foo
/home/my-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/home/my-virtualenv/src/bar
/home/my-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg
/home/my-virtualenv
/home/my-virtualenv/lib/python2.7
/home/my-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/my-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/my-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/home/my-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/my-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/my-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
```

Why is there a path from `/usr` before the paths from my virtualenv. And how to disable this?

Comment: If you wanted newer versions than were installed on the system already, *why did you use `--system-site-packages`*? The benefit of the virtualenv is that you get a clean start, so you can install the appropriate versions of only the packages you need.

Comment: In this context `--system-site-packages` gets used. I can't change it.